# How can I .htaccess 301 redirect all pages/files (except for one) to new domain?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I .htaccess 301 redirect all pages/files (except for one) to new domain?

I have already made an .htaccess file that successfully redirects most all the different pages and files on my old domain (www.olddomain.com) to my new domain (www.newdomain.com).

However, I need one page to not be redirected to the new site, that page is the Google verification .html file:

```
http://www.olddomain.com/googleverification.html
```

I have attached the most relevant parts of the file (.htaccess) pasted below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !.(php|html?|jpg|gif|png|pdf|tiff|bmp|ico|gz|zip|xml|txt)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1$2/ [L,R=301]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your first rule as:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/googleverification\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I tried the code but trying to access
    olddomain.com/googleverification.html
redirects to
    newdomain.com/googleverification.html

What I wanted to do is redirect
    olddomain.com to newdomain.com
but no redirect for 
    olddomain.com/googleverification.html

Comment: There is no way it will redirect `/googleverification.html` to new domain. Make sure this is **first rule** and you test after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: It works now, after I removed my first rule, my first 3 lines of codes.

Comment: I did add your codes at the top of all my other codes but I guess it conflicted with my existing codes. Removing the first 3 lines of of my existing codes above fixed the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, what's the NE flag for?

Comment: `NE` is for no encoding to handle special characters in URL

Comment: perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been asking the same question on different forums and another solution also works.

I just thought to share it here also.

```
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} !^www.newdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/googleverification.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```