# Redirect entire site except for one file with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a 301 redirect in place for a domain, however I am wanting to be able to access one page/file. How am I able to not include one specific file.

This is what I have now:

```
redirect 301 / https://example.com/
RedirectPermanent /  https://example.com
```

I am wanting to not include `https://example.com/administrator`

Comment: What kind of web server are you using and with what did you create this redirect?

Comment: Dedicated server. I used the .htaccess file.

Comment: excuse me I did not see the tags

Comment: In that case, though, the question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder)

Comment: @rpi I saw that question. I am not wanting to exclude an entire folder, but only one file.

Comment: you can rewrite the answer by removing the part about the slash. Then `http://example.com/administrator` wouldn't be redirected, but `http://example.com/administrator/` would

Comment: @rpi Sorry, not entirely sure what you are saying to do.

Comment: Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911687/how-can-i-htaccess-301-redirect-all-pages-files-except-for-one-to-new-domain)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177516/discussion-between-rpi-and-paul).

Comment: @Rpi I believe my internet settings are blocking the chat (I'm on a work computer)

Comment: Please check out the URL I wrote in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713997/redirect-entire-site-except-for-one-file-with-htaccess#comment90389885_51713997) comment

Comment: So this? `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/administrator [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]`

Comment: that would work